# How to resolve a Left Join sub-query error?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS-Access I'm trying to join three tables. The third table is created from a sub-query designed to aggregate dates because I don't want multiple records per day when aligned with the first table.

When I entered the left join sub-query, I got this error:

> The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to
>   add. Try inserting or pasting less data.

I've run the sub-query separately and it returns about 19,000 records. Which is quite smaller than the actual table. If I use the actual table, the query works just fine, but it includes the duplicate records when there is more than one entry per day on the third table.

```
SELECT
  SUM([ACD Calls]),
  (SUM([Avg ACD Time]*[ACD Calls])/SUM([ACD Calls]))/86400,
  (SUM([Avg ACW Time]*[ACD Calls])/SUM([ACD Calls]))/86400,
  ((SUM([Hold Time])/SUM([ACD Calls])))/86400,
  ((SUM([Avg ACD Time]*[ACD Calls])
    + SUM([Avg ACW Time]*[ACD Calls]))/SUM([ACD Calls]))/86400,
  SUM([Time Adhering])/SUM([Total Time Scheduled]),
  SUM([SS])/SUM([SO])
FROM
(
  (
    [GroupSumDaily]
    LEFT JOIN Adherence_WKLY ON (GroupSumDaily.[Day] = Adherence_WKLY.[Day])
    AND (GroupSumDaily.Agent = Adherence_WKLY.Agent)
  )
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT Evaluation_List.[Agent],
    Evaluation_List.Recording_Date,
    SUM(Evaluation_List.[Score]) as SS,
    SUM(Evaluation_List.[Out of]) as SO
    From Evaluation_List
    Group By Evaluation_List.[Recording_Date],
    Evaluation_list.[Agent]
  )
  as Evals ON (GroupSumDaily.[Day] = Evals.[Recording_Date])
  AND (GroupSumDaily.Agent = Evals.Agent)
)
WHERE
(
  [GroupSumDaily].[Agent] = "LastName FirstName"
  AND Month([GroupSumDaily].[Day]) =1
  AND Year([GroupSumDaily].[Day]) =2018
  AND [GroupSumDaily].[Day] > #2/23/2015#
)
```

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in the table where you're inserting the results? That error is usually about a string being too long.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a "main" table to query from.
I'd try removing the first two open brackets after the FROM statement (and their equivalent closing brackets.)
If that doesn't fix it, try moving the whole sub-query into a separate query and selecting from the results...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the subquery fields are automatically limited to 50 characters and this was the root of the problem. When I limited the return to LEFT([Agent], 50), the error disappeared. Is there a way to set character length is a subquery field?

The other odd things is, none of my fields were actually over 50 characters... when I ran Select [Agent] Where LEN([Agent]) >= 50, it returned only 1 records, and it was the "NEW" blank record from the bottom. I confirmed that it completely blank, with no spaces or tabs. Very confusing.